# How can I figure out what elements to use as parameters for cssQuery

Tags: java, maven, web-scraping

I would really want to understand how to actually extract the data I want from a website. I have done it with an IMDb top chart that I got from a tutorial on YouTube but it just confuses me how to know what syntax to insert for the row.select parameters.

I have tried doing it with other websites such as Best Buy, getting the price and name of specific laptops and I failed because I am pretty sure I put the wrong parameters(cssQuery).

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Scraper {
static  String title;
static final String url  = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top";
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {

    final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    for(Element row: document.select("table.chart.full-width tr")){
            final String title = row.select(".titleColumn a").text();
            final String rating = row.select(".imdbRating").text();
            System.out.println(title);
            System.out.println(rating);
   }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

for what i have undersnd from our question is that you dont know which css class t put in your code. for that you could inspect website by right-clicking on the website and click inspect element and from there you can check the div class by pressing ctrl+shift+c and hover over any element on the website like i have shown in below image
[image]